# How to print a list of guild members?

Tags: discord.py, python-3.7

Here's the code:

```
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    for member in ctx.message.guild.members:
        print(member.name)
```

Results: Discord Bot

How can I make it print every member in the guild, **including** the Bot?

(my version is 3.7.3)

Comment: you need to enable intents.members

Comment: Disregard, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable "Privileged Gateway Intents" in bot settings: [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications)

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents=intents=discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot('!',intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is Online!")

@bot.command()
async def members(ctx):
    member = ctx.guild.members
    for member in member:
        print(member.name)

bot.run("TOKEN")
```